# Slim3 redirect GET request as POST request

Tags: php, slim

Just started learning `Slim3`. Have been spending some time figuring out how to perform redirects with overriding original request type with no success.

I want the `/origin` route to perform the redirect to `/dest` route. 
`/origin` route receives `GET` request performs validation and after success redirects with `POST` request to `/dest` uri route. Here is the screenshot. I think I am doing something dumb here:

```
$app->get('/origin', function($req,$res,$args)
{
    $req= $req->withHeader('X-Http-Method-Override','POST');
    return $res->withRedirect('/dest');
});

$app->post('/dest', function($req,$res,$args)
{
    echo "this is destination page";
});
```

Comment: You cant redirect/change a clients GET request into a POST, /origin should be a post, then its possible

Comment: Please don't ever post pictures of code, it makes it hard to read, and we can't copy it to replicate your problem. Please edit your question and paste in the actual code text instead. Make sure to use ``` tags to format it as code.

Comment: Lawrence, appreciate your response. However, I am confused about the solution provided by the documentation suggesting that original request method can be overridden by using either by 1)including _METHOD parameter in the body of a request 2) a custom X-Http-Method-Override HTTP request header.

Comment: This is not specific to a framework or language. Please read this question for more information https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comment, this is not possible as the request made by the browser is not in your control.

When you call `->withRedirect()` you are sending a status code of `302` and a `Location` header to the HTTP client (web browser usually).

The web browser sees the [`302`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.3) status code and then issues a new request to the URL in the `Location` header. The server has no control over this request and every web browser makes a `GET` request.

Now, if you want to redirect a `POST` request to another URL and *keep the same POST method*, then you can use the [`307`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.7) status code with a `Location` header and the browser should do the right thing. Note that this code does not let you change a `GET` into a `POST` - it just keeps the same method as the original request for the followup redirection request.